# look for ip address and change the language of the website

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to know how can i add some script (javascript or maybe in PHP) to look for ip address and if ip is for sweden change the language of the website to Swedish , maybe change the location example.com/en to example.com/se or something like that ,
Thanks

Comment: Don't do that! IP-based language selection is horribly wrong. Parse the `Accept-Language` header the browser sends and use that to select the default language.

Comment: @ThiefMaster care to delv some practical examples as to why it is horrible idea? a link perhaps

Comment: Common sense. Just because I'm e.g. on vacation in country X it doesn't mean I speak that country's language. If my browser tells the site that I prefer e.g. an english website that's much stronger than the fact that my IP is from coutry X.

Comment: Anyways doing reverse GeoLocation is not quite accurate. You may get incorrect results. Also, IP can be easily changed to represent altogether a different location.

Answer (score 2):

You want do what's known as GeoLocation

You could do this with [MaxMind](http://www.maxmind.com/en/home)'s database and then process this in either your PHP app or as an Apache Module.

I'd advise that you recommend a language/locale option to users when they visit the site but ultimately allow them to override this.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the browsers accept-language header first, then the browser identification string which might contain the OS language.

```
function getDefaultLanguage() {
   if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]))
      return parseDefaultLanguage($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]);
   else
      return parseDefaultLanguage(NULL);
   }

function parseDefaultLanguage($http_accept, $deflang = "en") {
   if(isset($http_accept) && strlen($http_accept) > 1)  {
      # Split possible languages into array
      $x = explode(",",$http_accept);
      foreach ($x as $val) {
         #check for q-value and create associative array. No q-value means 1 by rule
         if(preg_match("/(.*);q=([0-1]{0,1}\.\d{0,4})/i",$val,$matches))
            $lang[$matches[1]] = (float)$matches[2];
         else
            $lang[$val] = 1.0;
      }

      #return default language (highest q-value)
      $qval = 0.0;
      foreach ($lang as $key => $value) {
         if ($value > $qval) {
            $qval = (float)$value;
            $deflang = $key;
         }
      }
   }
   return strtolower($deflang);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's a good idea or not, but heres how you'd do it:

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=?', function(data) {
        if (data.countryCode == 'SE') {
            $('body').text('Välkommen till Sverige');
        }else{
            $('body').text("You're not Swedish ?");
        }
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/2tVY8/)

Without jQuery, I guess the easiest would just be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var lang = function(data) {
        if (data.countryCode == 'SE') {
            //swedish
        } else {
            //not swedish
        }
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=lang"></script>​
```

or in PHP ?

```
<?php
    $json = json_decode( file_get_contents('http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json') );
    if ($json->countryCode == 'SE') {
         //swedish
    }else{
         //not swedish
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortly, based on pure JavaScript, you can do...

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>...</title>
  <script language="JavaScript">
    var lang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
    //alert(lang);
    if(lang == "en" || lang == "eng" || lang == "engs") {
        window.location = "en/index.html"; //English
    }
    if(lang == "sv" || lang == "swe") {
        window.location = "se/index.html"; //Swedish
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```